# Multiple Ajax Requests and Bandwidth

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, performance, browser

I' am trying to upload file in parts / chunks using **HTML5 File API** to slice down each part.

I' am confused over a point. My Team Lead said that sending 04 parts at once would be better using 04 different Ajax Requests and when one of them completes we will send another one so there will always almost 04 Ajax Requests running. My argument with this strategy is that when we send 04 Ajax Requests at once then first of all those 04 requests will be handled by browser and it depends upon browser how many concurrent requests it can handle to same server and secondly bandwidth will be consumed by all 04 Ajax Requests.

For example if I' am getting a upload speed of 100 KB and I want to upload 12 MB file and want to send it in 1 MB chunk then if I send 04 Ajax Requests then all of them will be getting 25 KB/sec because our bandwidth is common and all requests will be sharing same bandwidth. In this way each 01 MB chunk will take longer to finish but the advantage is that we are uploading chunks at once.

My opinion is that we should send 01 single 01 MB sliced Ajax Request at a time so that it consumes all available bandwidth. My point is that if you are downloading one file then it will consume all available bandwidth but it you start downloading more files all of them will be sharing same bandwidth hence resulting in increase of time for all downloads but smaller downloads can be finished concurrently and we don't have to wait for one complete file to finish downloading.

Please! share your ideas that what will be the best approach in my scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no right or wrong here. Write tests to see the effects of each approach. And try to define the typical user and the file size so you can calculate better. In fact there is no difference between waiting 1min for 4 chunks to be finished or 1min for one whole file...

Comment: @SvenSchneider: I agree with you that there is no right or wrong way. But I want to get an idea on what would be the best strategy in this scenario :-).